# Saving fragment state on navigating up

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Situation**:

Starting from my host activityA/fragment A, I click on a button to start host activityB/fragment B. Fragment B is a fragment which enables filtering options for Fragment A. After selecting the options, the user can press the navigate up button to return to fragment A.

**Problem**:

I would like the state of the options selected to be retained when navigating to Fragment B more than once. Since this is a filtering option, it would be preferable to not save this in storage beyond the duration of the application (It's just filtering. Not necessary to keep the information stored for a long time. Just in between navigation).

**Things I've tried**:

- OnSavedInstanceState - realized that onNavigateUpTo() / finish() don't trigger onSavedInstanceState
- android:launchmode="singleTop" - Because the activity is finished and destroyed from the backstack, no instance of the activity is available to receive the new intent.
- setRetainInstance - Activity is destroyed so attached fragment also destroyed.

A possible solution I've found is to use setResult and return the values to Fragment A. Then put these values as EXTRAs into a new intent when starting Fragment B again. This solution seems clunky. Is there a cleaner solution that just allows Fragment B to "remember" its state instead of passing values back and forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have stated the fragment is destroyed when user goes back so there is no way to get the "state" back. Also it does not make sense to store state as logically the fragment/activity is not needed from platform point of view.

So the way to 'remember' the state of fragment is to store the filter data in some other variable(s) and give it back to it when it is re-launched. What you are trying to do it perfectly fine i.e. return the filter data as result and send it back to fragment at re-launch.

To make it simpler you may write a class containing all the filter options and make it `Parcelable`. You may choose to make it a global so that you may not need to send it across activities, I would not prefer to do that though.

One UX issue is when user presses up/back it is generally expected that user has cancelled the operation. I as a user expect when I press back it cancels the operation and when I press "apply" it applies the filters. You may need to rethink about the user experience about applying filter on back press.